# Keyboard navigation/search for all UI elements

Tags: gnome, keyboard, docky, accessibility

I have recently found out about [Shortcat](http://shortcatapp.com/), an OSX app that allows for keyboard-only control of any application that has accessibility features turned on. I vaguely remember GNOME Do and Docky planning to head in that direction, and I am not sure what came of it with GNOME Shell---I tried searching just now and found nothing.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do in Linux? Is there such a app, or something similar, at least in spirit?

Comment: For the app menu at least there is the Unity HUD, of course. As for general control over _all_ UI elements, I have yet to see an application that can do that on Linux. Would love to have something like this, though.